# How to convert sun.nio.fs.ZipPath to sun.nio.fs.UnixPath in Java?

Tags: java, io, nio

When I run my app in standalone mode it works fine, but when it comes to fat jar to run it fails. It uses Path to fetch some resources. I figured out that fat jar version uses **sun.nio.fs.ZipPath** and it's getFile method throws an error. 3rd parth lib that I'm using has some method that accepts *Path* type as an argument.

So I need convert ZipPath to UnixPath.

Comment: You can only "convert" by unzipping the fat jar before using it. Individual entries in a Zip file do not have a `File` object because they are not individual files on the file system (unless your OS actually presents Zip files as directories).

Comment: If you _must_ use `Path` then either extract the resource to some location in the default file system or use the _ZIP File System Provider_. The latter lets you access a ZIP/JAR file as a virtual file system. If your third-party library has an overload that accepts `URL` or `InputStream` then you should access your resource the "proper" way—via `Class#getResource`, `Class#getResourceAsStream`, and other related API.

Comment: @Slaw agree that InputStream (or Path without getFile, and Files.newInputStream) is better. Note - OP is already using the ZIP File System Provider - the ZipPath class is part of it.

Comment: @Slaw thanks for the info. It turns out my lib offers Inputstream so I figured that out in that way.

Comment: More context is needed here. You can't of course use a Path to an entry in a zip file to locate a file on the default file system. Similarly, you can't use a Path to a file on the default file system to locate an entry in a zip file. So I think more context is needed here to explain what you are trying to do. The zip file system provider has improved significantly in recent JDK releases and it's a lot more functional (and reliable) that it used to be.